# ScrollVIew and GridView

Tags: android, java

GridView внутри ScrollView не работает, совсем не работает. В чем может быть проблема? Все атрибуты правильные, а без GridView работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**GridView**, также как и **ListView** и **RecyclerView**, изначально скроллятся самостоятельно. Им не нужен ScrollView в качестве родителя.

Если же вы используете GridView в качестве не единственного потомка ScrollView, то надо знать, что это плохая практика, не рекомендуемая в виду низкой производительности.

**UPD_0:**

Если всё же нужно, то попробуйте вот так: [тык](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26852498/3212712).

Comment: По идее, он находится в CardView, и потом CardView находится в ScrollView, и вот мне нужно, чтобы эти карточки скроллились, так как их много, в каждом CardView находится GridView. Мне это нужно. Как можно это обойти?

Comment: обновил ответ.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб сделал просто через tablelayout

Answer (score 0):

Добавте свойство в ScrollView:

```
android:fillViewport
```

А в GridView укажите высоту и ширину match_parent.